# How to generate the bernoulli tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, bernoulli-probability

How can I generate a tensor in `tensorflow` of `Bernoulli distribution` with factor  `p` ?

For example:

`a = tf.bernoulli(shape=[10,10], p)`

generates a matrix `10x10` of 0-1 where each element of matrix is one with probability `p` and zero with probability `1-p`.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve my problem! :D
The following code generates, what I need where `p=0.7`:

```
p = tf.constant([0.7])
r = tf.random.uniform(shape=shape, maxval=1)
b = tf.math.greater(p, r)
f = tf.cast(b, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Bernoulli distribution](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Bernoulli) from [Tensorflow probability](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability) library which is an extension built on Tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
x = tfp.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=0.7).sample(sample_shape=(10, 10))
x
```

This will output

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10, 10), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)>
```

The other method is to use a similar class from [`tf.compat`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/distributions/Bernoulli):

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.compat.v1.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=0.7).sample(sample_shape=(10, 10))
x
```

You will get `x` as you want but also a bunch of deprecation warnings will fall. So, I would recommend to use the 1st variant.

Also take into account that when I tested this code the latest version of `tensorflow_probability` library required tensoflow>=2.3 installed.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `tf.random.Generator.binomial`? It does not require installing tensorflow_probability.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/Generator#binomial

```
rng = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(seed=234)
rng.binomial(shape=[10], counts=1.0, probs=0.7)
```

When counts = 1.0, I think the binomial is the same as the Bernoulli.

The output of the above will be as follows:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(10,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>
```

Answer (score 0):

bern = tf.distributions.Bernoulli(probs=p)

x = bern.sample([10, 10])